# Who is this...? Array...?

Tags: riddle, word

> *You can find me as a veg,*
>   *In a series I'm a language.*
>   *But now, my hair is gray,*
>   *In short, I'm Array...*

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is:

> Bean[s]

You can find me as a veg,

> Bean is a veg

In a series I'm a language.

> Rowan Atkinson is in the TV series Mr. Bean

But now, my hair is gray,

> Mister Bean (Rowan Atkinson) is getting old and grey like all of us (http://www.gstatic.com/tv/thumb/persons/56849/56849_v9_bb.jpg)

In short, I'm Array...

> Array=RA=Rowan Atkinson.

Comment: You're almost right, it's the same person but there's something more with the lines $2$ and $4$. $+1$

Comment: @AK19 still no clue as to what the 4 might be.

Comment: Array = RA (in short)

Comment: Got it!!!.........

Comment: Rowan Atkinson is in a series of movies playing Johnny English.

Comment: @ErickWong Or, more relevant, he is in the Mr. Bean series.

Comment: @rhsquared How is that more relevant?  Johnny **English**.  The answer is Rowan Atkinson, not bean.

Comment: @ErickWong Because JavaBEANS is a programming language facility and because it fits better my initial guess. I suppose I can keep changing my answer but then again you can post yours if you disagree with mine.

Comment: @rhsquared Fair enough, answer posted.

Comment: @rhsquared The correct answer is Rowan Atkinson, please update your answer. And I really intended **Johnny English** as Erick Wong has posted.

Comment: @Ak19 I appreciate what you are saying but I'm not going to update anymore my answer because I didn't reach to this conclusion myself. One could argue that the rest of the lines were a bit vague and not well enough defined so they could lead to different answers.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. I respect your decision : )

Answer (score 6):

Drawing heavily on rhsquared’s attempt, the answer is...

> Rowan Atkinson

You can find me as a veg,

> He is most famous for portraying the character Mr. **Bean**.  Beans may technically be a legume, but colloquially they can reasonably be classified as a vegetable.

In a series I'm a language.

> He has starred in a series of movies as the would-be spy Johnny **English**.  English is a language.

But now, my hair is gray,

> He is now 64 years old — gray hair is to be expected.

In short, I'm Array...

> His initials are RA, a rebus for **Array**.

Comment: Well done!!!!! +1